# Magento 2 Label translation showing braces

Tags: curly-braces, magento2.2

Labels showing multiple translations between double curly-braces.
I have this problem both on the front and backend of Magento 2.

This is what I've tried so far:

- Cleared and flushed the cache
- re-deployed static content
- Updated Magento 2.2.5 to 2.2.6

Please look at the pictures for more info

Magento 2 Frontend

[image: Magento 2 frontend]

Magento 2 Backend

[image: Magento 2 backend]

Any ideas?

**Solution**
It's not a pretty fix but I've restored both js-translation.json files at the static frontend and backup folder.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue, this issue comes when you did not properly disable the configuration or inline translation configuration.

please check the inline translation or any other configuration and make sure you disable the configuration properly which applies to specific mode(developer) and before updating.

After that please run the following commands

> ```
> $rm -rf var/cache/* var/view_processed/* generated/code/*
> $php bin/magento setup:upgrade
> $php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
> $php bin/magento setup:di:compile
> $php bin/magento cache:clean
> $chmod 777 -R app/ var/ generated/ pub/
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have all php dependencies installed correctly?

Solution was suggested on this stackexchange thread: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/245516/why-are-the-admin-labels-showing-curly-braces

Comment: Thank you, but no this is not working. I've tryed a different server where an other Magento 2 installation is running fine. But the issue persist.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue several times, and don't know why its happening, but this solved my problem:

> Manually delete **generated/metadata, generated/code, var/cache, var/page_cache, pub/static** (be careful not to delete htaccess files),
>    then run **setup:upgrade,** **setup:static-content:deploy** and **cache:clean.**

Hope it helps.